# How to install ipdb for anaconda on linux?

Tags: python, linux, anaconda

My question is like: (only for linux)

[How to install ipdb with Anaconda on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553942/how-to-install-ipdb-with-anaconda-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

On a linux miniconda2 system, I did the following:

```
cd ~/miniconda2/bin
easy_install ipdb
```

This installed:

```
~/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipdb-0.9.0-py2.7.egg
```

`ipdb` was then present in the `miniconda2/bin` dir and I was able to use `ipdb` from the cmd line with no problems

I would guess anaconda will be very similar to miniconda and this approach should work for both

This approach was based on the answer given to your link to the similar windows based question. I had previously tried to install through conda with no luck, i.e.

```
$ conda install ipdb
Fetching package metadata: ....
Error: No packages found in current linux-64 channels matching: ipdb

You can search for this package on anaconda.org with

    anaconda search -t conda ipdb

You may need to install the anaconda-client command line client with

    conda install anaconda-client
```

Comment: I did that and the ipdb appears on the location you mentioned. But, still it is not recognized: 'global name ipdb is not defined'. What do you recommend?

Comment: I also get the following exception: "MultipleInstanceError: Multiple incompatible subclass instances of TerminalIPythonApp are being created." in the ipython notebook. How can i solve it?

Comment: do you have something like this in your .bashrc? export PATH=/$HOME/miniconda2/bin:${PATH}

Comment: also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20243754/multiple-incompatible-subclass-instances-of-interactiveshellembed-are-being-crea